# The tablewidget gets overwritten by the next header

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea

The header of the next group overwrites the table of the one before. Any ideas on how to protect the table before? I tried to use the spacer but it did not work. Any other ideas how I can solve the problem?
I have a header with e.g. an account number and a name. Below I want to list all the postings. But this program is not only for one account. It is for 100+ accounts to document the balances at a give date. (e.g. at the end of the year)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog, QWidget,
QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,QScrollArea,
QVBoxLayout,QListWidget,QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem)

from    PyQt5.QtCore       import Qt, pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal, QSize, QDate


import sys

class Dialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(64,64, 1000, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollarea.setFixedWidth(990)
        self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        widget = QWidget()
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(widget)
        self.layout_SArea = QGridLayout(widget)
        self.layout_All   = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_All.addWidget(self.scrollarea)

        for i in range(1,20,2):
            self.layout_SArea.addWidget(QLabel("I am the header"),i,0)
            self.tableWidget  = QTableWidget()
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(12)
            for x in range(10):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem()
                newitem.setData( Qt.EditRole,'{:0,.0f}'.format(x))
                newitem.setFlags( Qt.ItemIsSelectable |  Qt.ItemIsEnabled )
                newitem.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(x, 0, newitem)
            self.layout_SArea.addWidget(self.tableWidget,i+1,0,i+1,5)
            
        self.layout_All.addLayout(self.layout_SArea)
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row span argument indicates how many "row cells" the in the grid are occupied by the item, so it should not use the row *index*.

Change to:

```
    self.layout_SArea.addWidget(self.tableWidget, i+1, 0, 1, 5)
```